# How does Apache server serve multiple users efficiently?

Tags: php, apache

Here is a php code that I've used to demonstrate this

```
<?php
    sleep(5);
    echo "Finished<br>";

?>
```

Now, what I did is started 3 instances of the web browser and refreshed the page almost
simultaneously. But, the time took to load the pages took almost 15 second. And each of them loaded one after the another.

Then, How can an Apache server handle multiple users ?

Comment: You probably have your Apache configured to serve only one request at once (per IP). Apache is capable of serving many requests at once, multi threaded if you configured it correctly.

Comment: Yup and I hope you didn't try this with a standalone server. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: How can I configure Apache to serve multiple requests to one ip ?

Comment: It occurs to me to ask, is this Windows or Linux? If it's Windows, did you fire up Apache as a **Windows Service** ? Coz if you didn't, maybe that's why it's only handling one thread at a time.